# What does 'Some' mean?

Tags: class, swift

What does the 'Some' mean in the Swift debugger printout?

 ...and is this the default 'class' value? and if so... how would it change?

**Note:** 'Some' appears to point to a default class.

```
(lldb) po rootNode
Some
 {
  nodeValue = 10
  leftNode = Some {
    nodeValue = 1
    leftNode = nil
    rightNode = Some {
      nodeValue = 2
      leftNode = nil
      rightNode = Some {
        nodeValue = 3
        leftNode = nil
        rightNode = Some {
          nodeValue = 4
          leftNode = nil
          rightNode = Some {
            nodeValue = 5
            leftNode = nil
            rightNode = nil
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rightNode = nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`Some` is one of the two cases of `Optional`:

```
enum Optional<T> : Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init()
    init(_ some: T)
    var hasValue: Bool { get }

    /// Haskell's fmap, which was mis-named
    func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
    func getMirror() -> MirrorType
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> T?
}
```

You can extract the value by unwrapping the optional with `rootNode!`.